# How to respond to prompts from a process spawned with `exec`?

Tags: php, linux

I need to execute a series of commands on the OS from my PHP script. One of the commands, after being executed, prompts the user to enter a password, then enter password again (to verify the first input). How do I respond to these prompts from PHP?

Comment: What commands are you trying to execute? The command might allow you to pass credentials on the command line (i.e. `foo -u myUser -p myPass`) and you can avoid any sort of interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly do that with `exec`. You can do it by using [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead; be sure to read the examples and comments to avoid some common pitfalls.

Of course, possibly in your specific case maybe the problem can be circumverted by writing a shell script that feeds predetermined input into the spawned process's STDIN instead; this could end up being simpler, if not as "pure".